# plotting using evaluate

Tags: plotting

I have some simple equations such as

```
y = {Log[211998.4494776678` Sqrt[1/x]], 
Log[476459.98170463066` Sqrt[1/x]], 
Log[678088.9271561779` Sqrt[1/x]], 
Log[971047.7450193425` Sqrt[1/x]], 
Log[1.5926863743297434`*^6 Sqrt[1/x]]};
```

when i plot the using the evaluate command, i get a different result. i was wondering which one is correct the figure.
or simply, what does evaluate do with the figures? i know it's because of the logarithm plot, but why?

```
LogLinearPlot[Evaluate[y], {x, 1, 1000}, Frame -> True]
LogLinearPlot[y, {x, 1, 1000}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: the smae equation with differnt results]

Comment: I think the correct one is the top one, and you should define your function to plot as Set (y[x_]=...) or SetDelayed (y[x_]:=...) for obtaining the correct behaviour without evaluate

Comment: thank you very much, it was useful. @Fraccalo

Comment: What version are you using? With V12 on macOS, I get the same plot (the top one) regardless of whether I use `Evaluate` or not. I would not expect `Evaluate` to have any effect in this case.

Comment: @ MassDefect i am using version 11 on windows. i do get different plots in my version. the solution was to use y[x_] instead of y

Answer (score 3):

It appears you changed your code, your second plot was originally a "LogPlot"

in v12 atleast, it was the only way I could replicate your second plot, using your code.

```
LogLinearPlot[Evaluate[y], {x, 1, 1000}, Frame -> True]
LogPlot[y, {x, 1, 1000}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I am using version 11 and in my version, it does show different plots. the solution was the on that Fraccalo said.  i did not change the code by the way.